# C++ subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files

trying out putting classes and objects in header files and keep getting this error, not sure whether its because i havent included the correct files or its just written incorrectly. 
error is on line 28: iItemPrice[iCount]

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include "ItemsClass.h"
#include "A2main.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
ItemsClass::ItemsClass()
{
}

void ItemsClass::enter_items() {
    string sItmes[5];
    string sChoice;
    int iCount;
    int iItemPrice;
    int iNumOfItems;


    do {

        cout << "--------- ENTER NEW ITEMS ---------\n\nPlease enter the item Name: ";
        cin >> sItems[iCount];
        cout << "\nPlease enter the price of: " << sItems[iCount] << "\n";
        cin >> iItemPrice[iCount];
        cout << "\nWould you like to enter another item? Y/N \n";
        cin >> sChoice;

        if (sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y")
        {
            ++iCount;
            ++iNumOfItems;
        }

    } while ((sChoice == "Y" || sChoice == "y") && iNumOfItems < 5);

}
```

Comment: Please don't rewrite code into your questions. Copy-paste it instead. If you rewrite, you might, by mistake, add irrelevant errors. Which you have done.

Comment: As for your problem, what *is* `iItemPrice`? Why do you think you would be able to index it like an array?

Comment: And regarding "irrelevant" problems, what is the initial value of `iCount`? Remember that uninitialized local (non-static) variables will have an *indeterminate* value, and using them without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

iItemPrice is declared as an int. Not an array/pointer.

Declare it as:

```
int iItemPrice[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

`iItemPrice` isn't an array. If you want to create an array use `int iItemPrice[size]`, even better use `std::vector<int> iItemPrice`

Comment: Why would you need a vector when you know the size at compile-time?
it's just an unnecessary overhead.
`std::array` is the c++ way to do that.

Comment: i tried using vectors but couldnt get them to work with references like iCount etc

Comment: iCount is not a reference. Its a variable of type `int`

Comment: i mean to use it to access the array, i couldnt get that to work with vectors

Comment: @limpz Since you have a compile-time fixed-size array (or rather want one) then use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, like `std::array<int, 5> iItemPrice;`. If you want a run-time expandable "array" then [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) like `std::vector<int> iItemPrice(5);  // Create a vector with an initial size of 5 elements`